# c# how to make visual studio designer show base classes components aswell

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I have a class

```
public abstract class BaseFormClass : UserControl
```

and another class:

```
public class DerivedFormClass : BaseFormClass
```

if i open design view on baseformclass it show 3 components at the top.
but if i open derivedformclass, it does NOT show these 3 components, I have tried declaring 
InitializeComponent virtual and overriding, but this made no difference.

Its annoying as if i run it then it displays fine, but i want it to work in designer so it easier to work with in future.
any ideas?

Comment: are you able to post your constructors? I have a similar class hierarchy and I think mine works like you are expecting... I have an `InitializeComponent()` in both the base and inherited constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what works,

'both' class definitions need to extend the base class
so designer and general

```
public partial class BaseFormClass : UserControl
```

...

```
partial class DerivedFormClass: BaseFormClass
```

...

then the DerivedFormClass's designer will show the components from the BaseFormClass,

an alternative is to just define the baseformclass and then user that control in teh derived form class, 
but this depends on what you need to implement.